# Dev-C++ not compiling

Tags: c, dev-c++

Forgive the newby question. I am using Bloodshed Dev-C++ to start writing code in C. I keep getting the error that my code is not compiled when I go to run it.

I had a similar issue in Code Blocks. I have double-checked my code (will post below in case I am just missing something obvious), and it will not compile despite showing no errors. When I run this code in an online C compiler it works fine. I have to use Dev-C++ for class, so I need to figure this out. I have tried a few suggestions from the forums, but none have worked so far. Anyone have any ideas what could be causing this? I know it is likely user error.

```
/*Mark A. Oakley*/
/*CECS 130-150*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("\nC you later\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The results of this are it compiles without any errors, and states

> source file not compiled

The full log message is:

```
: Compiler: Default compiler Executing g++.exe... g++.exe 
"C:\Users\marka\OneDrive\Documents\UofL MS in CS\CECS 130\Practice Progamming\C Chapter 1\Untitled2.cpp" 
-o "C:\Users\marka\OneDrive\Documents\UofL MS in CS\CECS 130\Practice Progamming\C Chapter 1\Untitled2.exe" 
-I"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\include" 
-I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\backward" 
-I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32" 
-I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2" 
-I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include" 
-L"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib" 
Execution terminated
```

Comment: More information would be invaluable. Can you describe more accurately what happens when you  try to compile? The code in itself is fine

Comment: It compiles without error, then states "source file no compiled"

Comment: When I look at the log, i get: Compiler: Default compiler
Executing  g++.exe...
g++.exe "C:\Users\marka\OneDrive\Documents\UofL MS in CS\CECS 130\Practice Progamming\C Chapter 1\Untitled2.cpp" -o "C:\Users\marka\OneDrive\Documents\UofL MS in CS\CECS 130\Practice Progamming\C Chapter 1\Untitled2.exe"    -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\include"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\backward"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include"   -L"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib" 
Execution terminated

Comment: I've never personally used that compiler, but according to someone on yahoo answers, it will show the message 'Execution Terminated' even when compilation succeeds. Can you check whether it produces a file at `C:\Users\marka\OneDrive\Documents\UofL MS in CS\CECS 130\Practice Progamming\C Chapter 1\Untitled2.exe` ?

Comment: Take my word and never ever use GCC 3.x throw it away never look it back. GCC is aruond 9 nowadays; You can use MSys2 https://www.msys2.org/ or mingw64 if you want compiler only https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/ Also DevC++ is too out of date even wxDevC++ is out of date like nothing else. Try VisualStudio or CodeLite something even VisualStudioCode would do better than DevC++... Also if you really want something hipster like DevC++ try this one its best out there https://www.ultimatepp.org/ :)

Comment: Nick-there is an output of Untitled3.exe, but it was when I did not know to save as a C output and it was "Hello World." It did the same thing. I am hopeful that I can find another compiler that works

Comment: Abdurrahim-Thanks. I have loaded VisualStudio. I have not tried it yet (holding off on restarting until I finish something else I was working on). I hope it will work. DevC++ was what the professor recommended...so that's what I used. As long as I can get the output files he wants-I should be good to go.